# Colon/Asterisk as a filename delimiter?

Tags: windows, filenames

I'm looking for a character to use a filename delimiter (I'm storing multiple filenames in a plaintext string). Windows seems not to allow `:`, `?`, `*`, `<`, `>`, `"`, `|`, `/` and `\` in filenames. Obviously, `\` and `/` can't be used, since they mean something within a path. Is there any reason why any of those others shouldn't be used? I'm just thinking that, similar to `/` or `\`, those other disallowed characters may have special meaning that I shouldn't assume won't be in path names. Of those other 7 characters, are any definitely safe or definitely unsafe to use for this purpose?

Comment: why create problems for yourself? go with the common ones, like dash "-" or dots "."

Comment: The bad news is: on many UNIX systems the only character that's not allowed in a file name is "/". All others are valid (though they might need escaping to hide them from the shell for example).

Comment: You can use '/' in UNIX paths (but if you do this you are Satan). Just about the only thing you can't use is null.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The characters `:` and `"` are also used in paths. Colon is the drive unit delimiter, and quotation marks are used when spaces are part of a folder or file name.

The charactes `*` and `?` are used as wildcards when searching for files.

The characters `<` and `>` are used for redirecting an application's input and output to and from a file.

The character `|` is used for piping output from one application into input of another application.

I would choose the pipe character for separating file names. It's not used in paths, and its shape has a natural separation quality to it.

An alternative could be to use XML in the string. There is a bit of overhead and some characters need encoding, but the advantage is that it can handle any characters and the format is self explanatory and well defined.

Comment: `"`is not allowed in a path: it is considered a delimiter which surrounds a path when it contains special characters, but it is not part of the path.

Comment: @Adrien: It certainly is. It can either be used around the entire path or around an element in a path, like C:\"Program Files"\Adobe.

Comment: @guffa: i do insist, is is not. double-qoutes are used as a mean to escape special character, spaces to be precise. they are specially interpreted by Windows shell and command prompt, but are not part of the filename at all. can you show me a way to create a file whose name contains double quotes, using either the command prompt or Windows API ?

Comment: @Adrien: A file name does not contain quoation marks, and I have never said that they do. A path can contain quotation marks used to specify the components of the path, just like colon and backslashes are used in a path to separate the components although a file name never contains a colon or a backslash.

Comment: well, sorry for the stubbornness, i never thought of it this way but you are definitely right.

Comment: NTFS also uses `:` for streams.

Answer (score 8):

Windows uses the semicolon as a filename delimiter: `;`. look at the PATH environment variable, it is filled with `;` between path elements.

(Also, in Python, the `os.path.pathsep` returns `";"`, while it expands to `":"` on Unix)

Comment: Strange, though, that I can create files with semicolons in them.

Comment: that's strange, but that's the way it is... when you add a path which contains a ´;´ to the %PATH%, the added path is surrounded by `"` (which is not allowed in a path). maybe surrounding filenames with `"` and separating them with `;` is your solution.

Comment: If you surround the filenames with `"` then you can use almost any other character as the delimiter, such as a comma. Then you could utilize a common CSV reading routine to parse the string into an array.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `*` in the past. The reason for portability to Linux/Unix. True, technically it can be used on those fileysystems too. In practice, all common OSes use it as a wildcard, thus it's quite uncommon in filenames. Also, people are not surprised if programs do break when you put a `*` in a filename.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the *appearance* of a colon, and will be creating it programatically, why not make use of a UTF-8 character that just *looks* like a colon?

My first choice would be the Modifier Letter (U+A789), as it is a typical RTL character and appears a lot like a colon. It is what I use when I need a full DateTime in the filename, such as `file_2017-05-04_16꞉45꞉22_clientNo.jpg`

I would stay away from characters like the Hebrew Punctuation Sof Pasuq (U+05C3), as it is a LTR character and may mess with how a system aligns the file name itself.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. Also, upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to *create* files programmatically with every possible character except `\`. (At least, this was true at one time and it's possible that Windows has changed its policy since.) Naturally, files containing certain characters will be harder to work with than others.

What were you using to determine which characters Windows allows?

Update: The set of characters allowed by Windows is also be determined by the underlying filesystem, and other factors. There is a [blog entry on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_dewey/archive/2004/01/19/60263.aspx) that explains this in more detail.

Comment: If you try to rename a file in Windows Explorer, it comes up with that list, and stops you from doing it. I just assumed that it was like that at a fundamental level - but you're saying it's not so?

Comment: There are a lot of layers below Explorer. :) I've updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Doesn't : separate a file into different forks...name:text, name:data, etc?  And how do you get a slash into a file name on Windows?  I am under the illusion that it treats slash and backslash as equivalent at the system call level.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29 for information on alternate data streams (which I called 'forks').

Comment: NTFS alternate data streams are (not surprisingly) an NTFS feature. The valid set of characters in filenames on Windows *depends on the underlying filesystem and subsystem*. I suspect you can create a file with a `:` in the name using the Posix subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use any character with ALT key combination like  ‡ (Alt + 0135) as delimiter ?

Comment: That's a legal character in filenames and cannot be used as a seperator for that reason.