# Error with filename

Tags: ruby, filenames

I have a filename declared like this;

```
filename = Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")+'.json'
```

and the error occurs when I do this

```
File.open(filename,'w') do |f|
 f.write(rsp)
end
```

Error is in `initialize' : Invalid argument - 18:28:20.json which I assume is beacuse of a filename. When I do some 'normal' name everything works OK, so any tips?

Comment: What if you try to use underscore instead?

Comment: @KleberS. the underscores solved it, how do I change status to this question as solved or something, sorry my pesky questions?

Comment: You have to choose an answer and mark it to change the status as solved. I have just posted an answer with my previous help, so you can check it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
filename = Time.now.strftime("%H_%M_%S")+'.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses the colon as a drive letter separator; 
see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665724/colon-asterisk-as-a-filename-delimiter) for other special chars.

Use a different separator. You might be able to escape it, but IMO, not really worth it.

FWIW, for timestamped filenames I tends towards `yyyymmdd-hhmmss` or similar anyway.

For things like files it's always good to include more-complete info in the question--that naming conventions are different across OSes is well-known.